# How do I open Class Objects dynamically in the VBA editor without opening the editor?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Edit: See my comment below for a partial solution.

Edit 2: I found an adequate solution for closing the VBA editor but just want to see if anyone knows how to make it fully invisible the whole time. What I have found out works for my needs but I will leave this thread open for anyone who wants to elaborate on another method or expand on mine.

Original Post: I have a function that creates tables, queries, and forms. For the forms, it copies a template form and calls a function that replaces the forms VBA code dynamically. The below function I created works great, however, if I do not have the class object form open in the editor, I get the Run-Time error '2516': "Microsoft Access cannot find the module 'SPCInputFormVBA.', where SPCInputFormVBA is a variable for the class objects name. To further elaborate on the behavior, if I have the editor closed, as long as the module or class object is open in the editor, it will still work. I would like to be able to activate the corresponding Form_xyz object in the editor without the editor opening so that I can use this function to do a bunch of stuff to the to it. I am using a template form because there are a lot of things nested in it and has a lot going on. The form I can change the record source and various other things in it just fine, but the VBA portion is elusive to me so far. I thought opening the object would be easy but I am having a lot of trouble and cannot find a way to describe my issue that leads to me finding a solution.

```
Public Function InputFormVBA(SPCInputFormVBA)


DoCmd.OpenModule (SPCInputFormVBA)
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application.Modules(SPCInputFormVBA)
        For i = 1 To .CountOfLines

            If InStr(.Lines(i, 1), "TempTable") > 0 Then

             '   .ReplaceLine i, "           If DCount( ""serial"", """ & tblName & """, _"

            End If

            'If Instr(.Lines(i, 1), "

        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

The closest I have come is trying various things with this function in order to help me understand how Access will react to different potential solutions I find online:

```
Sub PrintOpenModuleNames()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim modOpenModules As Modules

    Set modOpenModules = Application.Modules

    For i = 0 To modOpenModules.Count - 1

        Debug.Print modOpenModules(i).Name
        'DoCmd.OpenModule (modOpenModules(i).Name)

     Next

End Sub
```

The `'DoCmd.OpenModule (modOpenModules(i).Name)` is commented out in this example and will open things, but it only sees things that are open already which doesn't help me. I do understand that there are different types of Modules, but I am not sure how to distinguish and the documentation online explains a general difference but doesn't reveal any way to reach out to the Class Object unless it is open in the editor already. Hoping someone can help or even correct my terminology if it is off and steer me to an existing solution elsewhere on the site.

Comment: I have figured out a partial solution.

I feel silly for making this so complicated on myself. If you are having a similar issue, you can simply: DoCmd.OpenForm (Variable), acDesign.

That will allow access to its Class Object instance in the VBA editor. It will open the VBA editor so I just need to figure out how to prevent that or to find a way to dynamically save and close the editor after it does its thing.

Comment: I have found out that I can use: Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False to close it. It is only open for a split second and I don't see that as being a big deal. Anyone have another way where it will hide it entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the VBE object model to access your form's code module without opening it in the VB Editor.  And with that approach, the VB Editor window does not need to be visible or open.  If the VB Editor window is not open, accessing the module this way will not open it.  So I think that satisfies the main objective of your question.

It's possible to use VBE with late binding but, since you're not familiar with it, you'll likely want to use early binding instead.  If so, add *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility* to your project's references.

Here is a very minimal procedure which only shows you how to reference a code module by name and print 2 of the module's properties.

```vb
Public Sub InputFormVBA(ByVal SPCInputFormVBA As String)

    Dim objModule As CodeModule

    Set objModule = Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents(SPCInputFormVBA).CodeModule
    With objModule
        Debug.Print .CountOfDeclarationLines
        Debug.Print .CountOfLines
    End With
End Sub
```

If your database contains only one VBA project, `VBProjects(1)` will reference it.  But if the db contains more than one VBA project, you may need to give `VBProjects()` a different number.  I presume you'll figure that out pretty darn quick.  :-)

A `CodeModule` object has methods you should find useful, including: 
`DeleteLines`; `Find`; `InsertLines`; and `ReplaceLine`.  However I don't really know what you want to do with the module's code, so will just leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful and exactly what I needed.